# How do you migrate existing data with Subsonic migration?

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic-active-record

I watched the http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_SimpleRepository screencast, but I am left wondering... how do you migrate existing data? Assume you decided to split a Name property into a FirstName and LastName. How do you do this in Subsonic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the data migration manually. There are several options you can choose from:

- SQL scripts
- write a simple program
- use an ETL Tool like SSIS or Talend

Comment: Subsonic seems to do the schema migration automatically.. can this be saved to a schema migration file ?

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic won't do this for you, you'll need to write data migration code/sql yourself. Also you should be aware that the migrations are not designed to be used in a live environment.